# Processing WM_PAINT

Tags: c, winapi, wm-paint

I have read many examples on the internet but I'm still stuck. I'm trying to process the WM_PAINT message sent to my application.

In my application, I always draw in the same DC, named `g_hDC`. It works perfectly. When `WM_PAINT` is received, I just try to draw the content of my `g_hDC` into the DC returned by `BeginPaint`. I guess `g_hDC` contains the last bitmap that I drawn. So I just want to restore it.

```
case WM_PAINT:
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;

 int ret;
 HDC compatDC;
 HDC currentDC;
 HDC paintDC;
 HBITMAP compatBitmap;
 HGDIOBJ oldBitmap;

 paintDC   = BeginPaint(g_hWnd, &ps);

 currentDC = GetDC(g_hWnd);
 compatDC  = CreateCompatibleDC(paintDC);
 compatBitmap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(paintDC, CONFIG_WINDOW_WIDTH, CONFIG_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
 oldBitmap=SelectObject(compatDC, compatBitmap);

 ret = BitBlt(compatDC,
              ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.top,
              ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top,
              currentDC,
              ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.top,
              SRCCOPY);

 ret = BitBlt(paintDC,
              ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.top,
              ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top,
              compatDC,
              ps.rcPaint.left,
              ps.rcPaint.top,
              SRCCOPY);

  DeleteObject(SelectObject(compatDC, oldBitmap));
  DeleteDC(compatDC);
 DeleteDC(currentDC);

 EndPaint(g_hWnd, &ps);
```

break;

But it just draws a white rectangle ... I tried many possibilities and nothing works. Can you please help me?

Comment: c++ tag is not correct. Change it to Win32.

Comment: You have not drawn anything in compatBitmap - what you expect to see after BitBlt? Suppose there must be "noise" i.e. random image.

Comment: I removed the c++ tag. I'm just seeing a white rectangle at the place of the overlapping window.

Comment: I think you will see the same white rectangle without BitBlt - it is the normal background erase (white).

Comment: But why my old g_hDC is not restored ?

Comment: Are you sure that `g_hDC` is valid and does have something in it? Try painting something (`Ellipse()` or `Rectangle()` will do) into `g_hDC` before you do the `BitBlt()`. And... surely you were closer to the mark when you started: you need to use `hdc` to draw on, not just to create a compatible DC from.

Comment: I don't think you need a compatible bitmap in this case either - `hdc` is the screen DC, ready to use.

Comment: At no point do you draw into the DC returned by `BeginPaint`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you are doing wrong.

First, your saving `g_hDC` is relying on an implementation detail: you notice that the pointers are the same, and thus save the pointer. This may work in the short term for a variety of reasons related to optimization on GDI's part (for instance, there is [DC cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/06/01/612970.aspx)), but will stop working *eventually*, when it is least convenient. Or you may be tempted to use the DC pointer when you don't have the DC, and will scribble over something else (or fail to do so due to GDI object thread affinity).

The correct way to access the DC of a window outside its `WM_PAINT` is by calling `GetDC(hwnd)`.

`CreateCompatibleDC()` creates an in-memory DC compatible with `hdc`. Drawing to `compatDC` is not enough to draw to `hdc`; you need to draw back to `hdc` after you draw to `compatDC`. For your case, you will need to have two `BitBlt()` calls; the second one will blit back from `compatDC` onto `hdc`. [See this sample code for details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You cannot `DeleteObject()` a bitmap while you have it selected into a DC. Your `SelectObject(compatDC, oldBitmap)` call needs to come *before* `DeleteObject(compatBitmap)`. (This is what i486 was trying to get at in his answer.)

(I'm sure this answer is misleading or incomplete in some places; please let me know if it is.)

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried with the second BitBlt and I get the same result. A white rectangle. I also tried with the code example you provided. Same result.

Comment: I edited my first post with the code I'm testing at the moment. I have still the white rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to delete bitmat: `DeleteObject( SelectObject(compatDC,oldBitmap) );` - without DeleteBitmap on prev line. `SelectObject` returns current (old) selection as return value - and you delete it. In your case you are trying to delete still selected bitmap.

PS: I don't see `CreateCompatibleDC` - where you are creating compatDC? Add `compatDC = CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );` before `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.

Comment: Thank for your response. I edited the code in my first post. It still doesn't work. (note that I now BitBlt into compatDC instead of hdc). The problem is that I don't understand what I'm doing. It's not logical for me. Why should I create a compatibleDc so that BeginPaint already gave me a DC ??

Comment: The idea with DC-s is very strange. I have used it for years and still cannot understand fully the idea - but this is the method for work. DC is the object where you draw - something like virtual display. It can be the real display, can be memory virtual display, can be printer surface. I am not sure whether your g_hDC contains valid bitmap and is compatible with hdc/compatDC. If you `BitBlt` from g_hDC to compatDC, you will need extra `BitBlt` to transfer image from compatDC to hdc (real display). Try this instead `BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,compatDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);`.